# Does a spinning object acquire mass due to its rotation?

Tags: special-relativity, mass, angular-momentum, terminology, mass-energy

We have settled on a standard way of expressing  mass at relativistic speeds, as per [Matt Strassler's](https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/mass-energy-matter-etc/more-on-mass/the-two-definitions-of-mass-and-why-i-use-only-one/)  excellent blog.

That is no problem for linear momentum, mass is invariant.

All I want to know is does the same principle apply to **angular** momentum, for every object, from golf balls to neutron stars? Or have I pushed the invariance idea into the wrong area?

EDIT I just discovered this post [Does rotation increase mass](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/146853/does-rotation-increase-mass?rq=1) and I really want to avoid semantics about the word mass, but it seems to say mass does increase  END EDIT

Comment: Read Ben's answer to the earlier question more carefully. He uses exactly the same example system I used and get the same result (though expressed in slightly different language).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The mass of a extended body in rotation *is* larger than the mass of the same body not rotating, but that increase in mass should *not* be attributed to any change in the mass of the constituent particles.

Here I am defining the mass of an object (in the usual manner of modern treatments) as the square of that object's energy-momentum four-vector:
$$ m \equiv \frac{1}{c^2}|\mathbf{p}|^2 = \frac{1}{c^2}\sqrt{E^2 - (\vec{p}c)^2} \;.$$ Such masses are Lorentz invariants: they do not change under a Lorentz boost (change in inertial velocity). This is the only meaning of "mass" in modern treatments and in particular the phrase "relativistic mass" is nowhere to be seen.

There is kinetic energy in rotation and that energy contributed to the time-like component of the four momentum (i.e. the $E$ above).

To expand on how the overall body can grow more massive while the particle that make it up do not, we have to examine the four-momentum of a compound system.

Like other vectors, you can add four-vectors component-wise. So trivial compound body consisting of a symmetric rigid<sup>1</sup> rotor of total mass $M_\textrm{rot} = 2m$ when not rotating and separation $r$. At a given moment each sub-mass has  three-momentum $\pm\vec{p}$ in the rotor's COM frame and therefore energy $E = \sqrt{(\vec{p}c)^2 + (mc^2)^2}$ in the same frame. That makes their total four-momentum
$$ \mathbf{P}_\textrm{tot} = \left( 2\sqrt{(\vec{p}c)^2 + (mc^2)^2}, \vec{0} \right) \;.$$
The mass of the rotor is 
\begin{align*}
M_\textrm{rot}  
&= \frac{1}{c^2} \left| \mathbf{p}_\textrm{tot} \right| \\
&= \frac{1}{c^2}E^2 \\
&= 2\sqrt{\left(\frac{\vec{p}}{c}\right)^2 + m^2} \;.
\end{align*}
This obviously exceeds $2m$ for any non-zero $\vec{p}$.

The basic lesson here is that the mass of systems is *not* automatically the sum of the mass of the parts in relativity; a matter often inexplicably left off of lists of things that are different in Einstein's world. One of the most interesting games you can play with this fact is showing that two photons (each of exactly zero mass using the definition above) can none-the-less form a system of non-zero mass.

*A word of caution:* I've not considered the binding energy of this system which would not be acceptable in a serious treatment as any rotation swift enough to make an appreciable difference to the mass of the system would also necessarily alter the binding energy by an appreciable amount (that is, the assumption of rigidity would be violated).

---

<sup>1</sup> I know. No truly rigid bodies in relativity. We can assume this thing isn't actually rigid but that we spin it up slowly enough to pretend.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I know about half of what you have written, I also now know much more about how subtle it can be. This is a 3 beer, ( or possibly aspirin), read through answer you have given me . Much appreciated though.

Comment: In general, in baryons with the same quark content but different $J$, the one with higher $J$ is heavier, right? Obviously your caveat about binding energy applies strongly since it's the strong interaction, though.

Comment: So what mass M do you use when you apply a force to the center of mass of your rotating body (angular velocity $\omega$) and want to know its change of linear momentum $\vec P=M\vec v$, in Newton's 2nd law $\vec F=\frac {d(M \vec v)}{dt}$?

Comment: And what mass do you use for the rotating body to calculate the gravitational force according to Newton's law of gravitation? $$F=G\frac{m_1m_2}{r^2}$$

Comment: @freecharly you use $M_{rot}$ in both cases.

Comment: @Virgo - That's what I also suspected. The funny thing is that this virtuous joggling with the four-momentum boils down to the simple addition of the relativistic energies of the two masses in the center of mass frame $$E_{tot}=M_{rot} c^2= 2 m_{rel} c^2=2\frac {mc^2}{\sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}}$$  Thus, as expected, the **relativistic mass** $$M_{rot}=\frac{E}{c^2}=2m_{rel}$$ is just the sum of the maligned **relativistic masses** $$m_{rel}=\frac {m}{\sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}}$$ where $p=m_{rel}v$.

Comment: @freecharly No one is arguing about the outcome of this calculation. You *can* do math that way, but the concept has been largely abandoned by those communities that do relativity all the time for a reason. The concept of relativistic mass gives you a mental toolbox that makes questions like http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3436/ and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/180698 sound like they are based on good reasoning despite the fact that the answer is obvious if you know the theory well. The second one is particularly insidious.

Comment: @dmckee - Thank you very much for this interesting link! I agree on  the advantage of using four-vectors  and of the Lorentz invariant mass. As far as I understand, this invariant mass is the same as the "relativistic mass" defined by $m=E/c^2$ where E is the total energy  in the center of mass frame of reference. I think that the use of the term "relativistic mass" should not be banned as long as it is clear what is meant by it.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, the mass increases according to the energy you've added by $E=mc^2$.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, if you don't mind I will hold off accepting your answer, obviously we can call mass whatever we like for the particular problem, but the inconsistency, **if** there is one,  bothers me.

Comment: Yes this is the easy answer, which always holds. How much energy will you have added relativistically when you bring a body with classical inertial moment $I$ to an angular speed $\omega$?

Comment: Additional question: What happens to the circumference if the rotating body is a circular disk? Does $\pi= circumference/diameter$ change its value?

Comment: I think you are right, linear momentum is treated different than angular momentum and invariance is used only when needed. It's a choice **we** make, nature could not care less, so I am wrong to extend the invariance idea further than linear.

Comment: There is certainly a little extra energy held in the stress caused by the centripetal force. The stress-energy tensor, if used right, will include that energy. Also, there's energy (in the form of stress) in the different relative velocities (inner material wants to foreshorten less than external material). So the actual angular velocity calculated from the applied energy is less than a more naive guess at it. So a precise calculation almost needs to be done numerically rather than analytically because those stresses are likely non-linear. @freecharly-it wants to shrink.

Comment: it wants to shrink from the foreshortening of the outer surface, but it want to expand because of the centripetal force.

Answer (score 7):

I am only considering Special Relativity. When the rotating object is composed of particles with rest mass $m_i$ with rotational speed $v_i=r_i\omega$, where $r_i$ are the distances to the rotational axis and $\omega$ is the angular velocity, the total rest mass of the object is $M= \sum_i m_i$ and the relativistic mass is $$M_\textrm{rel}=\sum_i \frac{m_i}{{\sqrt{1-(v_i/c)^2}}}=\sum_i \frac{m_i}{{\sqrt{1-(r_i\omega/c)^2}}}$$ This doesn't include additional potential energy due to internal tension in the rotating object. The sum can also written as an integral over mass elements dm.

Comment: Thank you, this should be an obvious thing, but since I joined this site, lots of things that I assumed to be true, are not. Regards

Comment: @CountTo10- You are right. I have had similar experiences. Greetings

Comment: -1: The answer is incorrect because the op is asking **"Does the inertia of a body depend upon its energy content?"** and the answer to that question is yes; and the concept of relativistic mass needs to die.

Comment: @Robin Ekman - The question of the OP is **"Does a spinning object acquire mass due to its rotation?"**. You can easily check this by reading the title. If "the relativistic mass needs to die" then also Einsteins formula $E=mc^2$ needs to die?

Comment: That question is a special case of the one I quoted, which is the title of Einstein's paper. And yes $E = mc^2$ needs to die in favor of the *correct* $E^2 - p^2 = m^2$.

Comment: For an spinning object shouldn't we consider the moment of inertia as  a 'mass'?

Comment: @AMS - I am not sure about the definition of moment of inertia in Special Relativity. In any case, the increase of energy of an object due to its rotational energy should also increase its **relativistic  mass** according to $M=E/c^2$.

Comment: @Robin Eikman - According to John Roche, cited here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_special_relativity , the term  **"relativistic mass"** is still used by 40% of modern authors and in many introductory physics texts. I don't think that its use should be ostracized by overzealous purists as long as it is clear what is meant by it.

Comment: At least 40% of introductory physics texts are crap.

Comment: The point is that *professionals in relativity* don't use that outdated concept. No one is arguing that the math doesn't work out, they are arguing that the conceptual structure is unnecessarily cumbersome, hides the deep mathematical beauty of the subject, and provides the mental tools to make a whole class of mistakes that aren't made if you base your reasoning on quantities with well defined tensor characteristic under Lorentz transforms.

Comment: @dmckee - I fully understand your point that working with four-vectors and  tensors is essential and highly preferable for theoreticians. You mentioned the interesting case that a single photon would not have an invariant mass (as opposed to two). Hasn't Einstein (before GR 1915) heuristically used his $E=mc^2$ to conjecture that photons are subject to the gravitational force?